# Show duplicate record with group by in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Table and I am fetching records with the `GROUP BY`,
here is my query

```
SELECT max(fish_size), Fname, Lname, fish_species FROM comp_data WHERE junior = 'yes' GROUP BY fish_species
```

here is output

[image]

But there are 2 blue cod with 38.5cm so the result I want to get is this was it shows samantha and Ollies Blue cod

[image]

How I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your existing query is working because you are selecting 3 columns and grouping only 1 column which is incorrect and the query should fail.

I think this is what you are expecting:

```
SELECT max(fish_size), Fname, Lname, fish_species FROM comp_data
WHERE junior = 'yes' 
GROUP BY Fname, Lname, fish_species;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `rank()`:

```
SELECT cd.*
FROM (SELECT cd.*,
             RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY fish_species ORDER BY fish_size DESC) as seqnum
      FROM comp_data cd
      WHERE junior = 'yes'
     ) cd
WHERE seqnum = 1
ORDER BY fish_species;
```

Note that your query is broken, because the `SELECT` columns are not consistent with the `GROUP BY` columns.  Happily, MySQL no longer allows such broken, non-standard queries (with the default settings).  However you should also avoid writing them.  Using the setting `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` can help.

Comment: @sunilkumar . . . Your comment is unhelpful.  There is no obvious syntax error in the query.  You can set up a db/sql fiddle to illustrate the problem.